# Probability that sum of discrete random variables is smaller than other sum

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, summation, random-variables, density-function

Given an examplary discrete density function $f$:

```
Value probability
    1   15/50
    2   10/50
    3   7/50
    4   13/50
    5   5/50
```

What is the probability that $\sum\limits_{i=1}\limits^n\mathcal{X}_i > \sum\limits_{i=n+1}\limits^{2n}\mathcal{X}_i$ for 2n random independent variables $\mathcal{X}_i$ sampled in order $i=1,2,...,2n$ from that density?

My thought process: 
Let $\mathcal{X} = \sum\limits_{i=1}\limits^n\mathcal{X}_i$ and $\mathcal{Y}=\sum\limits_{i=n+1}\limits^{2n}\mathcal{X}_i$.
These are two new random variables, and their density function $g$ can be computed through convolution of $f$ $n$ times with itself, e.g. for n=3
it would be $g=f*f*f$.

Now let $v_{min}=n*min(values_f)$ and $v_{max}=n*max(values_f)$. The resulting possible values of the new random variables are all $k\in[v_{min},v_{max}]$; since the values of $f$ all have a distance of 1 to the next one all values in this intervall are possible.

Now I think that
$P(\mathcal{Y} < \mathcal{X})=\sum\limits_{k=v_{min}}\limits^{v_{max}}P(\mathcal{Y}<\mathcal{X} | \mathcal{Y}=k)$ =
$\sum\limits_{k=v_{min}}\limits^{v_{max}}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{y=v_{min}}\limits^{k}\sum\limits_{x=v_{min}}\limits^{y}g(x)g(y)}{\sum\limits_{y=v_{min}}\limits^{k} g(y)}$.

Is that correct? I feel like I made a mistake somewhere, but can't quite catch it.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you need an explicit formula or rather a statement of what happens as $n\rightarrow \infty$ (that the proba goes to 1/2)

Comment: If the probability $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)=q$ then the answer will be $\frac12- \frac{q}{2}$.  If I have read your description correctly, $q=\sum_y g(y)^2$

Comment: I need an explicit formula for a given n

Comment: Without a computer this will be rather messy for large n. If asymptotics is of use you may use a CLT which will probably be quite precise here.

Comment: I wrote a python script that does this, but I'm getting values greater than one, which is what is confusing me

Comment: Ok, then your formula is wrong. You should multiply by $P(Y=k)$ (so you should not divide by anything in the last). Alternatively use the suggestion by Henry above

Comment: For comparison I think you should get asymptotically something like $1/(2\sqrt{\pi n}\; \sigma)$ where $\sigma^2 = 1.9444$ is the variance of the above.

Comment: As mentioned before you should not divide by anything. The result is equivalent to $\sum_{y=vmin}^{vmax} \sum_{x=vmin}^{y-1} g(x)g(y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(\mathcal X < \mathcal Y) = (1 - P(\mathcal X = \mathcal Y))/2$, where $P(\mathcal X = \mathcal Y)$ is the coefficient of $x^0$ in $$A_n(x) = \left( \sum_j p_j x^j\right)^n \left(\sum_j p_j x^{-j}\right)^n$$

Comment: Only for $n=1$.

Comment: I see. Thanks. $ $

Comment: Or perhaps simply stick to the python script for computing iterated convolutions? (and summing the squares)

Comment: what do you mean @H.H.Rugh?

Comment: Just that you may compute your density functions $g_n$ using your python script. Then $P(X=Y)=\sum_k (g_n(k))^2$ and $P(X<Y)=(1-P(X=Y))/2$ as already mentioned. Btw, $P(X=Y)=0.2023030.../\sqrt{n}$ holds to a very good precision.

Comment: Alright thanks! The resulting value is somehow equivalent to $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{y=v_{min}}\limits^{v_{max}} \sum\limits_{x=v_{min}} \limits^y g(x)g(y)}{\sum \limits_{y=v_{min}} \limits^{v_{max}}g(y)}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** The following simulation in R is for $n =1000$. It simulates
100,000 $(X, Y)$ pairs. The simulated distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are very
similar. The actual distributions are discrete, but
nearly normal. As Commented, $P(X = Y)$ is very small, so $P(X < Y)$ is very
nearly $1/2.$

```
m = 10^5;  x = y = numeric(m); p = c(15,10,7,13,5)/50
for(i in 1:m){
  s1 = sample(1:5, 1000, prob=p, repl=T)
  x[i] = sum( s1 )
  s2 = sample(1:5, 1000, prob=p, repl=T)
  y[i] = sum( s2 )
}
mean(x < y)
## 0.49681
mean(x == y)
## 0.0062
```

Below are histograms of the simulated distributions of $X, Y,$ and $X - y$.
For large $n,$ normal approximations for $P(X < Y)$ and $P(X = Y)$
should be good enough to show the essence of the model for many purposes.
"Best-fitting" normal densities are shown.

[image]